# If I have 2 uncorrelated currencies, why is the volatility of their product higher than either of the volatilities? (better explanation inside)

Tags: fx, correlation

Let's say we have 3 currencies:

- EUR/USD
- USD/GBP
- EUR/GBP

For a minute let's assume that we calculated the EUR/USD-USD/GBP correlation for the last N days and the result was 0.0 (I know this is not realistic but please bear with me). Other assumptions:

- EUR/USD volatility = 0.1
- USD/GBP volatility = 0.06
- GBP/USD was fairly priced during the whole period (as in EUR/USD*USD/GBP = EUR/GBP)

We want to calculate what has been the volatility of EUR/GBP without knowing the prices (of EUR/GBP, but we know the prices of EUR/USD and USD/BP).

Using the triangulation method I get a volatility for the EUR/GBP of 0.117, which sounds weird. My intuition tells me that if the correlation between EUR/USD-USD/GBP was 0.0 during that period, the volatilities of EUR/USD and EUR/GBP should be equal.

Could somebody please explain if this makes sense?

EDIT to add:
From my calculations, to get a volatility of 0.1 for the EUR/GBP, the correlation between EUR/USD-USD/GBP should be -0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to @NHN's answer here, which is correct in the formula and its interpretation: for a Vol of 10% and 6%, respectively, the **equally-weighted portfolio** of 1 `EURUSD` + 1 `USDGBP` gives you a Vol of 11.6%.

However, the bold-faced words - **equally-weighted portfolio** - are key here; you need to consider that this FX cross is simply a portfolio of x `EURUSD` and y `USDGBP`, and you/NHN implicitly assigned a weight of 100% to the `EURUSD` (buy the `EUR`, sell the `USD`) and 100% to the `USDGBP` (buy the `USD` sell the `GBP`).

You can easily check that the variance of this very portfolio (1.36%) is just the sum of the two individual variances (1% and 0.36%, respectively); and this should make sense considering you assume a correlation of zero between the two.

Now I highlight this because of your statement in the question:

> We want to calculate what has been the volatility of `EURGBP` without knowing the prices.

If you do not know the prices of `EURUSD` and `USDGBP`, we (a) either stop here, or (b) simply *assume* 1 `EURUSD` + 1 `USDGBP` = 1 `EURGBP` like in the above calculation. But this is clearly not the case in reality; in fact, as of yesterday (rough numbers):

- 1 `EUR` buys you 1.2073 `USD`
- 1 `USD` buys you 0.7304 `GBP`

So to construct the vol of 1 `EURGBP`, you should be using weights of 0.8283 and 0.7304 instead of 100% and 100% (you should be able to verify these numbers very easily through a triangular calculation).

Using these weights, you'd get a *portfolio* (= `EURGBP`) volatility of 9.37%.

Comment: Thanks! This is much clearer. A couple of questions/clarifications: Could you explain a bit how do you get those weights through the triangular calculation? Not sure I follow you there. Also, in the quote of the OP you mention I meant the prices of `EURGBP` are not known but the prices of `EURUSD` and `USDGBP` yes. I edited the OP to be clearer about it. And lastly, how do you get the volatility of 9.37% using those weights? Might be because it's too early in the morning for me but I don't see it. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure - so basically, if `EURUSD` is 1.2073 then `USDEUR` is 0.8283, so selling 1 `USD` will deliver you 0.8283 `EUR`. To buy this 1 `USD` you sold, you'd need to spend 0.7304 `GBP`. Hence, `EURGBP` in an arbitrage-free FX spot market (ignoring bid-ask spreads) would need to be 1.2073 x 0.7304 = 0.7304 / 0.8283 = 0.8818. This is the price of 1 `EUR` expressed in `GBP`. So buying 0.8283 `EURUSD` and buying 0.7304 `USDGBP` will be the same as buying 1 `EURGBP`, which is the *portfolio* you're interested in.

Comment: Regarding the portfolio variance consisting of $w_A$ % of asset $A$ and $w_B$ % of asset $B$, you have $\sigma^2_P = w_A^2 \sigma^2_A + w_B^2 \sigma^2_B + 2 \rho_{A, B} w_A w_B \sigma_A \sigma_B$. In your case, $\rho_{A, B} = 0$, and $w_A = 0.8283$, $w_B = 0.7304$ and the two vols with 10% and 6%. Plug this into the above formula and take the square root, then you should end up with 9.37%.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Vol3 = sqrt (vol1^2 + vol2^2 +2* vol1* vol2*correl)

Where
Vol1 = vol eur/usd
Vol2= vol usd/gbp
Vol3 = vol eur/gbp

Comment: Yes, exactly like that is how I get to that result, but intuitively I still can't see why the vol is higher if the 2 currencies are uncorrelated. Intuitively if correlation is 0 the vol of EUR/USD and EUR/GBP should be equal to each other no?

Comment: No, if the correlation = 0, vol3 is always greater than vol1 and vol2. It’s straightforward from the formula, isn’t it?(sqrt(x) is square root of x)